# SwiftUI NavigationView with ScrollView with PageTabViewStyle()

Tags: swiftui

My goal to get a PageTabView that contains multiple NavigationViews which then contain a ScrollView. I expected it to work with this code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                ScrollView {
                    Text("Nav 1")
                    Spacer()
                }
                .navigationTitle("Scroll")
            }
            
            NavigationView {
                ScrollView {
                    Text("Nav 2")
                    Spacer()
                }
                .navigationTitle("Scroll 2")
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
    }
}
```

But the result in the simulator is this:

[image: Result]

Important for me here is that the NavigationView just contains the ScrollView to be able to change the navigationTitle to .inline when scrolling.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this a bug? I think I could solve this with a custom PageTabView from UIKit but I have no idea how to implement this in SwiftUI.

I tried "Yrb"'s answer with StackNavigationViewStyle(). Unfortunately, this gives me a weird behaviour:

[image: Weird behaviour]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `StackNavigationViewStyle()` like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                ScrollView {
                    Text("Nav 1")
                    Spacer()
                }
                .navigationTitle("Scroll")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline) // inline added here
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()) //Added here

            NavigationView {
                ScrollView {
                    Text("Nav 2")
                    Spacer()
                }
                .navigationTitle("Scroll 2")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline) // inline added here
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()) //Added here
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
    }
}
```

You are getting a Master Detail view. If you rotate the device, hit the back arrow, you will see it in landscape. Using a `StackNavigationViewStyle` prevents that from occurring.

Normally, it would go in the struct that contained the `NavigationView`, but because of your (appropriately) simple example, your `NavigationView` is in the `TabView`

Edit: This is what I was alluding to when I said "simple example". If you have any further questions about this, you need to ask a new question. SO posts are supposed to deal with the question and move on, not keep modifying the question. This is because someone else needs to see what was done here and be able to use it. It isn't fair to the next person to keep editing them.

That being said, here is my final edit to the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Navigation1()
                .tag(0)
            
            Navigation2()
                .tag(1)
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
    }
}
```

I added to separate views:

```
struct Navigation1: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                HStack{ //Remove this to see your "odd behavior"
                    Text("Navigation 1")
                        .padding()
                } //Remove this to see your "odd behavior"
                Spacer()
            }
            .background(Color.orange)
            .padding(.top, 30)
            .navigationTitle("Scroll 1")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline) // inline added here
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()) //Added here
    }
}
```

The only difference being the 1s are swapped for 2s, and I used different background colors. The behavior you were seeing is because when you were attempting to scroll the `Text()`, you were actually OUTSIDE the scrollview. You can see it if you remove the `HStack` from `Navigation1`. The background color will shrink to a column, and you will see if you try to scroll from outside of that, you will push the whole view up and down. This is EXPECTED behavior.

I added the padding because in this simple example, the design of the UI will run under the inline title. You will need to deal with that yourself. There are many options, but you have to decide how you want to handle it and look it up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this gives me a very weird behaviour of the .navigationTitle: When scrolling, it doesn't change to inline and scrolls with the ScrollView. Sometimes it changes to .inline but this is very laggy.

Comment: I edited my answer. That is actually a separate, but related issue in SwiftUI. You need to add `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)`

Comment: I understand your approach and I think I wasn't clear enough: I need to .navigationTitle only change to .inline when scrolling, like a "normal" NavigationView with a ScrollView in it would behave.